# Delete particular rows in R

Tags: r

In general, I know how to delete rows in R. However, for this particular requirement, I am unsure how to proceed. Here is an idea of what I need to do with data:

```
   ID        MONTH   INCOME
1. 00000012    6        60
2. 00000012    8        65
3. 00000015    12       70
4. 00000025    4        45
5. 00000025    8        60
6. 00000032    6        10
7. 00000035    6        30
```

Quick explanation of each column:

The first 7 digits of ID identify an agent. So, in row one, 00000012 means agent 1. The last digit is the interview number. So, in row three, 00000015 means agent 1, interview 5.

Month and income are straightforward.

**What Must Be Done**

I need to delete every ID that does not include both a 2nd and 5th interview.

I need to only have the max. month for the 2nd interview, and 5th interview for each ID.

So, if I cleaned the data properly, I would have:

```
   ID        MONTH   INCOME
2. 00000012    8        65
3. 00000015    12       70
6. 00000032    6        10
7. 00000035    6        30
```

Notice row 4,5 are gone because there was no 2nd interview for agent 2. Row 1 is gone because there was a higher month for agent 1, interview 2.

My current thoughts how to do this seem overly complex. I am thinking of breaking ID into two columns, one with the first 7 digits, another column with the last digit. Then, loop through the entire data, and at each row, run another loop to see if the ID that corresponds to the row has both an interview 2 and interview 5. If it does, fine. If it doesn't, I then have to delete all rows with that ID.

Next, I have to do a similar thing for deleting non-max months.

I feel like I could do the above, but it is very cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: The separation is a great idea, see `?substr`. Create an `agent` column and an `interview` column. Then you should find which agents **do** have a 2nd interview, `agents_with_second = data$agent[data$interview == 2]` and filter you data to only have those agents. `data = data[data$agent %in% agents_with_second, ]`

Comment: Thank you. The separation can also be done by having one column be the mod 10 of ID, and another column just an integer of ID/10. substr can work too.What about after that? Is looping through the only good way?

EDIT: Ah, great idea.

Comment: Yes, that would work if your ID is actually numeric. Since it starts with 0 I bet you have a string or a factor on your hands. To make your example reproducible, including data types, share your data with `dput(droplevels(head(data)))`. (Yeah, sorry, I was editing as you were commenting, apparently.)

Comment: Well, the ID in my R actually does not have the leading zeros, so I'll try this. I think I can get it from here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
library(stringi)
Agents <- substr(df$ID,1,nchar(df$ID)-1 )
A2 <- stri_endswith_fixed(df$ID,"2", fixed = T)
A5 <- stri_endswith_fixed(df$ID,"5", fixed = T)
A2and5 <- intersect(Agents[A5], Agents[A2])
df[Agents %in% A2and5,]
```

Comment: This almost worked perfectly.

The last line is giving me problems though, its making my df mostly collapse. May be just because A2and5 is a character though, not integer/numeric. 

Since my A2and5 is fine though, looping through it, and only keeping data where the ID matches will not be that big of a deal, although there is probably an easier way.

Comment: Great, that worked! 

Do you think I should follow a similar approach to then get the max. month?